# css box shadow on a div container cut off

Tags: css, dropshadow

edit: more general question:
I like the box-shadow on divs, however when I place a div directly below the box-shadow'd div, that bottom part of the shadow doesn't overlay on top despite messing with z-indexes.  So it seems like box-shadow cannot overlay another div?  Any ideas would be great!

original question-
I am using blueprint for a layout. This means there's a .container of `950px` which then contains a `#content`.

In this case the `#content` fills the whole container so is also `950px`.

I would like to have a drop shadow on the `#content`, but the problem is the shadow gets cut off since there is no space left to see it in the `.container`.

A workaround would be to decrease the width of the `#content` but that messes up the layout positionings I already have, and it looks too narrow.

Is there a way to get the box shadow to kind of ignore the parent container and appear over it?  This isn't blueprint specific I guess, but that's the context. thanks!

EDIT:

```
body .container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 950px;
}
body .container:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
#content {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 950px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px black;
}
```

`#content` is directly in `.container`.  If I put a drop shadow on `#content` you can't see it until I shrink the width, which messes with the inside elements.

Comment: Could you include a jsFiddle so we can see what restrictions or limitations there are.  I have some ideas, but depending on what you have to work with, they may or may not work.

Comment: How are you generating the drop shadow? (I didn't think CSS box-shadows got clipped by the parent container by default?) Can we see some code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would add some padding to the `.container` element and ensure that your `#content` stays at the width you need.

Comment: hmm yeah I think this may be the only solution...will mark it as answer if no one else comments with updated code...

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `overflow: hidden` on the `.container`, since you already use clear fix on it. So, you can just throw it away: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/gDXLf/

Answer (score 2):

It all depends what you are trying to achieve.

I was having difficulty with an inline-block group of list items. The right shadow was cut off by the list item next to it upon hover

A simple hack is to just add the following to the element:

```
li:hover {
    transform: scale(1,1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1,1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
    -o-transform: scale(1,1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1,1);
}
```

**[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DP8UX/)**

*Although, this may only work for specific scenarios. I have only tested it on my example above.*

Comment: cool, it works. appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could make the .container wider (960 is perfectly acceptable for a fixed width) and keep the #content centered inside the .container. Does that mess up anything for you?

Comment: hmm I could try that, except I am using the compass gem to make blueprint less inline with html. so the mixin it comes with makes the container 950 by default